# #incude "apstring.h" C++ isn't working anyone know?

Tags: c++

I have an error when I try to include apstring.h does anyone know an alternative code etc.? Here is the code where the error was.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "apstring.h" //error is located under #include, the error is     (Error: cannot open source file "apstring.h")
using namespace std;

int main()
{

system ("pause");
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What library is that from? Did you add that directory to your "include directories" (or equivalent depending on your compiler, etc)?

Comment: does that file truly exists in your working directory?

Comment: @CoryKramer I don't know lol I'm using the standard C++ Visual Studio Premium 2012 and whatever compiler it has. I got the code.

    #include "apstring.h"

from my intro to C++ programming book that I have.

Comment: `"apstring.h"` is not a header from the C++ Standard Library. Therefore, there are two other options: 1) You wrote that header 2) It is from some library. I'm assuming it is not case 1. Therefore, if you don't even know what library it came from, then what exactly do you want us to tell you? **Edit** I found the header [here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/download.htm) if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Check your book again, it must have created an "apstring.h" header somewhere

Comment: @CoryKramer is this the same thing as #include <string> or are they different?

Comment: @AndrewTew No not at all. [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) is the header that defines the C++ Standard Library string classes (e.g. `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc). `"apstring.h"` is some random library that I just found a few seconds ago, that I'm assuming is from some example textbook or something.

Comment: @CoryKramer How do I bring it over to my C++ files?

Comment: @CoryKramer I tried to include apstring to Visual Studio, but I couldn't so I decided to experiment and replace the apstring commands with (what I think are) string equivalents and the code worked the same way! I think my book is just outdated, it is from 2002 so :P.

Comment: apstring seems to be used more in the US in College Board http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/APstrings/APmain.htm  and http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/exact-difference-apstring-string-232762.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the header file here:
http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/apstring.h

And the corresponding cpp file:
https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/code/apstring.cpp

And you have to replace strcpy by strcpy_s in order to avoid security problem

Here is the link to my two files witch are working with your program in visual studio 2015:

http://pastebin.com/qanbAF1D

you have just to create a console app in visual studio, add your main file and the cpp file provided

and then add the header file in the part of adding header file named Header Files in visual studio

if you are under Linux you have to put the files in the same directory, but i didn't test that under Linux

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have downloaded the two files apstring.h and apstring.cpp and they are sitting on my desktop, where do I place them for them to be includable to a C++ Program. If you answer that then I will consider this question answered!

Comment: @AndrewTew Put them in the folder where your Visual Studio project is (next to main.cpp for example)